# Java-utilizing programs malfunctioning

Tags: java, screen-tearing

I've been having a problem for a while with programs that utilize java (e.g. Geogebra, Maple, MarvinSketch etc.). It's kind of an image distortion that changes when the cursor is moved around.

Interestingly Java IDEs like Eclipse and JCreator work just fine, the programs on them as well.

Here are some pictures:

- [First example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QNUpm.png)
- [Second example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4MBNl.png)

Things I have tried:

- Reinstall Java
- Clear Java cache
- Tried every possible compatibility settings
- Reinstalled the malfunctioning programs

I have the latest version of java (32-bit and 64-bit) installed on Windows 10. There are no issues with the hardware performance and all drivers are up to date.

Comment: Please use the image hosting service provided by Stack Exchange to host your images. It’s the image button in the editor’s toolbar.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't experienced the screen-tearing that you're seeing, but a recent update by NVIDIA caused Maple and other Java apps to crash. If you do have an NVIDIA card, it might be worth checking the driver version.

NVIDIA has posted a fix that resolves the issues with java crashing here: https://nvidia.custhelp.com/app/answers/detail/a_id/4378